# How can i get the change in value of an objects rotation between the current and previous frame, and use it in a driver

Tags: python, animation, rigging, drivers

I want to use the change in rotation between the current and previous frames to rotate another object.

EG object A was at 30 degrees in Z axis last frame,

and is now at 35 degrees in Z axis on the current frame,

so has changed by +5 degrees,

so i would want object B to rotate by +5 degrees.

How can i get Z rotation value from the previous frame, and use it in a driver?

I have practically no python knowledge but from other similar questions this might be the only way, but i don't understand how to actually make a script work with my driver.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy, copy

#get current frame
thisFrame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

#go back one frame
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(thisFrame -1)


#get z rotation of current object
print ("rotation on frame")
print (bpy.context.scene.frame_current)
print (bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2])

#set custom property ZrotLast to be the same as z rotation
last =copy.copy( bpy.context.object.rotation_euler)
bpy.context.object["ZrotLast"] = last[2]

#go back to current frame
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(thisFrame)

#set custom property ZrotCurrent to be the same as z rotation
bpy.context.object["ZrotCurrent"] = bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2]

#get z rotation of current object
print ("rotation on frame")
print (bpy.context.scene.frame_current)
print (bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2])

#work out difference between current and last frame
bpy.context.object["ZrotDelta"] = bpy.context.object["ZrotCurrent"] - bpy.context.object["ZrotLast"]
```

Please note DO NOT try changing **bpy.context.scene.frame_current** to change the frame! it will appear to work but it seems like nothing in the frame updates so you will get the same rotation information as the original frame, use **bpy.context.scene.frame_set** and it works correctly.